# Is "eventually" possible to use in that case

Tags: meaning

> 1. Could you let me know if the lp has been sent, I sent many emails then eventually I made a paypal claim . None of my emails have been replyed.

This sentence means that I stopped sending messages once the claim was done, but if I had kept sending emails after the claim, should I have written that ?

> 2. Could you let me know if the lp has been sent, I have sent many emails but none of them has been replyed and **eventually** I made a paypal claim.

I think eventually is not possible here  because it would mean that the paypal claim was the last thing I had done which was not true because I kept sending emails after the claim.

Comment: Was the fact that no replies were received the basis for making the claim?

Comment: Also, *send* and *reply* are separate actions. You don't say in either example that you sent emails after you made the claim.

Comment: But present perfect for send  that means up to now and past simple for make that means it is in the past, so obviously the claim was made before I sent my last email

Comment: [No one has **replied** to my emails. OR I have received no reply to my emails. OR There has been no reply to my emails.]

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

> None of my emails have been replyed.

One, the verb "reply" needs an object. Your emails have not been replied *to*. Or as a noun, "None of my emails received a reply."

I think the best way to phrase this is

> "Can you let me know if the IP has been sent? I have sent many emails
>   and received no replies, and I **also** submitted a paypal claim."

I would not use "eventually." Eventually implies a long and indeterminate passage of time. Using "also" here says that you are doing all of those things.

Comment: Is "Received" in your answer still in present perfect?